# Create if/else variables and preg match/replace based on variable string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a text area where our users can replace variables with real order data.

e.g. `{{service_name}}` would be replaced with "DJ Booth"

Now i am creating the ability to show certain text based on the service name. For example...

```
Some text at the start

{{if|service_name=DJ Booth}}
  This is the text for DJs
{{endif}}

Some text in the middle

{{if|service_name=Dancefloor Hire}}
  This is the text for dancefloor hire
{{endif}}

Some text at the end
```

Getting the preg_match to work over multiple lines was solved with `U` (non greedy) and `s` (multi line)

So the output now is....

[image]

The issue is that there could be multiple conditionals, so i cant just preg match the type and then print the value, as i need to loop over each match, and replace the text where it was matched rather than outputting at the bottom.

So i am using this...

```
$service = get_service();
preg_match_all("/{{if\|service=(.*)}}(.*){{endif}}/sU", $text, $matches);
$i=0;
foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
  if ($match == $service) {
    print $match[2][$i];
  }
}
```

Which matches correctly, but just outputs all text together, rather than in the same place they matched.

SO my question is....

- How to i get the replacement to happen in situ?

Thank you!

Comment: `s` pattern modifier for multiline dots.  Greedy matching is a bad idea `.*`.  What do the multiple condition declarations look like.  How are you wanting to match/avoid them?

Comment: @mickmackusa The multiple conditions are in that first bit of text at the top. The customer may wish to specify different text for a DJ, and different text for a Dancefloor, and only have that text show if that service is booked. The s for multiline unfortunately causes it to match the second {{endif}}

Comment: Its not twig, its a custom variable (placeholder) in a saas system. I have just found that adding a U to the preg match causes it to be "non-greedy", and the s allows multi line, I think ive sorted the multi line issues - just not replacing the text in place.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` to replace the matches once they are found.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew preg_replace_callback looks promising! Does it allow me to add a condition to first make sure the service name matches?

Comment: Yes, yes it does.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: service_name. The expected result is that if the service_name matches the one retrieved with get_service(), it will remove the if/else variabels and just show the text. If the service name does not match, it just removes the whole if/else section

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/PPeWLD, I am not sure what to do when the service name does not match the one you obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using your search variable in the regex pattern, you can target your desired placeholders.  You don't need to match/capture the search string, just the text that follows it.  Match the whole placeholder and replace it with the capture group that is wrapped in the conditional syntax.

- I am using `\R` to match newlines.
- I am using `\s` to match all whitespaces.
- `s` is the pattern modifier that makes `.` match any character including newlines.
- Matching the `\s` and `\R` characters outside of the capture group allows the replacement text to conform nicely with the neighboring text.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/c3vOK))

```
$text = 'Some text at the start

{{if|service_name=DJ Booth}}
  This is the text for DJs
{{endif}}

Some text in the middle

{{if|service_name=Dancefloor Hire}}
  This is the text for dancefloor hire
{{endif}}

Some text at the end';

$service = "Dancefloor Hire";
echo preg_replace("/{{if\|service_name=$service}}\s*(.*?)\R{{endif}}/s", "$1", $text);
```

Output:

```
Some text at the start

{{if|service_name=DJ Booth}}
  This is the text for DJs
{{endif}}

Some text in the middle

This is the text for dancefloor hire

Some text at the end
```

---

Extension:  If you want to wipe away all of the non-qualifying placeholders, perform a second pass and delete any remaining placeholders.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/sSToC)

```
echo preg_replace(["/{{if\|service_name=$service}}\s*(.*?)\R{{endif}}/s", "/\R?{{if.*?}}.*?{{endif}}\R?/s"], ["$1", ""], $text);
```

Comment: Oh my god thats so simple! I never thought about just inserting the service name into the regex!!! Thank you!

Now is there a way to remove the {{if|service_name=DJ Booth}}This is the text for DJs{{endif}} because it didnt match?

Comment: Okay, I'll add that in.

Comment: Mate thats spot on. I learnt a lot here today, especially doubling up with square brackets. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm still messing around with merging the two patterns.  https://regex101.com/r/y1mWvq/1  I'll ping you if I come up with something better.  I'm almost content: https://regex101.com/r/y1mWvq/2